# Joining on dates which are in between two entries

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

`DELIVERY as t1`

```
date,               driver_id

2016-01-01 13:44:22, 32
2016-01-02 13:14:58, 32
2016-03-05 13:14:55, 32
```

`DELIVERY` table has records when delivery pickup takes place.

and

`DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY as t2`

```
date,               driver_id, dispatch_id

2016-01-01 19:12:23, 32,        4
2016-01-07 11:16:58, 32,        3
2016-03-06 13:14:55, 32,        7
2016-03-06 16:54:12, 33,        8
```

`DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY` table tracks when driver was assigned to dispatch

My main goal is to `JOIN t1.date=t2.date AND t1.driver_id=t2.driver_id`to get `driver_id`

**The problem:** history table is not tracking assignments on daily basis, but rather uses intervals. If I assigned driver to dispatch one month ago, it will have only one entry. If I change dispatch for that driver today, it will add another entry as of today, also, if I change dispatch more than once, it will add multiple entries for the same day with different timestamps and I need to match delivery times in between assignments.

**Question:** while inner join is not a problem, I can't figure out the solution to fulfil the logic I outlined above.

```
SELECT 
 t1.date, t1.driver_id, t2.dispatch_id
FROM 
 DELIVERY as t1
INNER JOIN 
 DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY as t2
  ON t1.date=t2.date 
   AND 
     t1.driver_id=t2.driver_id
```

*Assuming that driver_id and dispatch_id are matching, and there could be many deliveries*

[image]

Comment: @RyanVincent What he wants is the dispatch ID from the most recent dispatch history before the delivery.

Comment: added an image to visualize the expected logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9696f/1)

```
SELECT D.date,D.driver_id,H.dispatch_id,
       H.startdate as `Dispatch_Start`,
       H.enddate as `Dispatch_End`
FROM DELIVERY D
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT H2.date as startdate,
      (SELECT MIN(date) 
       FROM DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY H1
       WHERE H1.driver_id = H2.driver_id AND H1.date > H2.date
       ) as enddate,
       driver_id,
       dispatch_id
    FROM DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY H2)H
ON D.driver_id = H.driver_id
AND D.date >= H.startdate
AND (D.date < H.enddate OR H.enddate IS NULL)
```

First you do inner selects and min(date) that's greater than the date to find enddate of the dispatch.  Then once you have table H it's easy to compare delivery's date with this H's dispatch date range.

I only got 2 rows back ...because looking at your first delivery it occurred before any dispatch has happened so it doesn't fit any date range.
[image: row that doesnt fit in any date range]

After reading @Barmar's logics i think it's simpler and i wrote another variation [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/794a8/1)

```
SELECT D.date,D.driver_id,
    (SELECT dispatch_id FROM DRIVER_DISPATCH_HISTORY as H
     WHERE H.driver_id = D.driver_id AND H.Date < D.date
     ORDER BY H.date DESC LIMIT 1) as dispatch_id
FROM DELIVERY as D
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the highest dispatch date that's lower than the delivery date. Write a subquery that finds this date, and then join that with the dispatch history table to get the dispatch ID.

```
SELECT x.driver_id, x.date, y.dispatch_id
FROM (
    SELECT t1.driver_id, MAX(t2.date) AS dispatch_date, t1.date
    FROM delivery AS t1
    JOIN driver_dispatch_history AS t2 
    ON t1.driver_id = t2.driver_id AND t1.date > t2.date
    GROUP BY t1.driver_id, t1.date) AS x
JOIN driver_dispatch_history AS y
ON x.driver_id = y.driver_id AND x.dispatch_date = y.date
```

Comment: I think this query works too if you add `GROUP BY t1.driver_id,t1.date` to the inner select

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that.

Comment: it's nice i like your solution.